# DataStore Full Text Search documentation?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

[This Google IO video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7B7FyU9wW8Y) from 2011 introducing the Full Text Search API (at 31:13), refers to DataStore Integration by setting a few properties in attributes.

However I can't seem to find any related documentation to show how to go about using this feature.

Does anyone know if anything's changed since the release of the API and if works in another way now?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To my understanding there is still no integration.